# Is that means vulnerable function If I execute shell code via program

Tags: shell, security

Lets say that I have a program and its name is : `EXEC`

Everytime I start the program with some code it executes the code that I wrote.

**For example :** If I write : `./EXEC cat /etc/shadow` I can see the shadow file.It executes `cat /etc/shadow`

I did some researches (actually did my best with my english level) and understood that it is a vulnerability.However I couldn't see any message that can answer my question.Therefore I want your helps.

How can that be a vulnerability ? May I got it wrong, is that really vulnerability ? Thanks for your messages from now.

Comment: Well, it's a vulnerability if the actual command executed (`cat` here) or its arguments come directly or indirectly from user input.

Comment: If you don't have the read right, then this is  `Privilege escalation`. This question better suited at Superuser or Information security.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you so much for your help but I couldn't understand the reason still.If an attacker wants to inject a shell code via that program (./EXEC python shell_code) he can inject it in a normal way (python shell_code).Is that accepting like vulnerability because these shell code functions are happening under the program's control ?

Comment: @kelalaka Im new sorry If it is wrong located.If it is not Privilege Escalation, I mean If it just executes codes for the user who writes.For example lets say that you can't read shadow file and you are a normal user but you can still execute some codes, is that still a vulnerability ?

Comment: See the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation).

Comment: @SefaAltın So if `cat /etc/shadow` gives `cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied` then `./EXEC cat /etc/shadow` will also do the same? That's not a security issue in itself. Unix already comes with such a standard utility: `env cat /etc/shadow`. However, if `cat` says "Permission denied" while `./EXEC cat ..` shows you the shadow file, then this may be a security risk